# Redirect output of a command to a text file in Haxe

Tags: cmd, haxe

I am trying to execute the following code in Haxe.

```
class File_Operations
{
    public static function main()
    {
        Sys.command("ipconfig",[">","C:\\Users\\ila5\\Desktop\\Temp.txt"]);
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error

```
Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.

USAGE:
    ipconfig [/allcompartments] [/? | /all |
                                 /renew [adapter] | /release [adapter] |
                                 /renew6 [adapter] | /release6 [adapter] |
                                 /flushdns | /displaydns | /registerdns |
                                 /showclassid adapter |
                                 /setclassid adapter [classid] |
                                 /showclassid6 adapter |
                                 /setclassid6 adapter [classid] ]

where
    adapter             Connection name
                       (wildcard characters * and ? allowed, see examples)

    Options:
       /?               Display this help message
       /all             Display full configuration information.
       /release         Release the IPv4 address for the specified adapter.
       /release6        Release the IPv6 address for the specified adapter.
       /renew           Renew the IPv4 address for the specified adapter.
       /renew6          Renew the IPv6 address for the specified adapter.
       /flushdns        Purges the DNS Resolver cache.
       /registerdns     Refreshes all DHCP leases and re-registers DNS names
       /displaydns      Display the contents of the DNS Resolver Cache.
       /showclassid     Displays all the dhcp class IDs allowed for adapter.
       /setclassid      Modifies the dhcp class id.
       /showclassid6    Displays all the IPv6 DHCP class IDs allowed for adapter.
       /setclassid6     Modifies the IPv6 DHCP class id.


The default is to display only the IP address, subnet mask and
default gateway for each adapter bound to TCP/IP.

For Release and Renew, if no adapter name is specified, then the IP address
leases for all adapters bound to TCP/IP will be released or renewed.

For Setclassid and Setclassid6, if no ClassId is specified, then the ClassId is removed.

Examples:
    > ipconfig                       ... Show information
    > ipconfig /all                  ... Show detailed information
    > ipconfig /renew                ... renew all adapters
    > ipconfig /renew EL*            ... renew any connection that has its
                                         name starting with EL
    > ipconfig /release *Con*        ... release all matching connections,
                                         eg. "Wired Ethernet Connection 1" or
                                             "Wired Ethernet Connection 2"
    > ipconfig /allcompartments      ... Show information about all
                                         compartments
    > ipconfig /allcompartments /all ... Show detailed information about all
                                         compartments
```

When I run the above command directly in cmd, it works well.

I would like to know how to redirect the output to a text file using Sys.command() in Haxe. Any ideas?

Comment: `cmd` handles redirection so `ipconfig` command has to be run in `cmd`. So preface the command line with `cmd /c`. See `cmd /?` for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that **">"** operator will be interpreted as an argument here (not as stdout redirection), but with Sys.command you can't avoid it.
What you can do is to read stdout of "ipconfig" command directly in haxe and save it as a file.
This sample code should work for you

```
var p = new Process("ipconfig", []);
var out:String = p.stdout.readAll().toString();
p.close();
File.saveContent("ipconfig.txt", out);
```